# URN in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, urn

So I need to get images and xml from a server using this URN thing.. but in all honesty I'm pretty confused about it so any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

For example, here is a citation to a high-resolution, full-color digital image of page 12 of the St. Chad Gospel from Lichfield Cathedral: `urn:cite:fufolioimg:ChadRGB.Chad012`. The citation is in urn format

Any image whose URN is known can be loaded into the Image Citation Tool by adding its URN to the address. By default, the tool’s address is this:

```
folio.furman.edu/projects/cite-roi/index.html?w=600&urn=urn:cite:fufolioimg:ChadRGB.Chad012
```

The CHS Image service understands these requests:

GetBinaryImage
GetCaption
GetRights
GetIIPMooViewer

I don't know how to use all this information to connect and get images or xml.

additional references to help:

- http://folio.furman.edu/projects/lawdi/index.html
- http://chs75.chs.harvard.edu/projects/diginc/techpub/cts-overview
- http://amphoreus.hpcc.uh.edu/tomcat/chsimg/requests
- http://www.homermultitext.org/hmt-doc/guides/ict.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page for your address contains this link:

```
http://amphoreus.hpcc.uh.edu/tomcat/chsimg/Img?&request=GetBinaryImage&urn=urn:cite:fufolioimg:ChadRGB.Chad012&w=3000
```

this redirects to

```
http://amphoreus.hpcc.uh.edu/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi?OBJ=IIP,1.0&FIF=/project/homer/Lichfield/ptiffs/Chad_RGB_ptiffs/Chad012.tif&RGN=null&WID=3000&CVT=JPEG
```

the image with a width of 3000px.

So you just need to download the image for this address

```
http://amphoreus.hpcc.uh.edu/tomcat/chsimg/Img?&request=GetBinaryImage&urn=urn:cite:fufolioimg:ChadRGB.Chad012&w=3000
```

There are thousands of answers on stackoverflow showing yow you can download something.

---

```
NSSTring urn = @"urn:cite:fufolioimg:ChadRGB.Chad012";

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://amphoreus.hpcc.uh.edu/tomcat/chsimg/Img?&request=GetBinaryImage&urn=%@&w=3000", urn];
```

<sub>I prefer using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/)</sub>

Comment: thank you!  so can I use functions here: http://folio.furman.edu/citecoll/testPage       in my downloading?

Comment: What xml are you talking about?

Comment: the translation in here  http://folio.furman.edu/lichfield/folio/overview?folio=urn%3Acite%3Afufolio%3AmsChad.1v

Comment: I dont see any xml, but html. please search for it on stack overflow. there are many posts regarding xml/html parsing.

Comment: oops i meant this http://furman-folio.appspot.com/CTS?withXSLT=chs-gp&request=GetPassagePlus&urn=urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0031.tlg001.lichfield001:1&inv=inventory.xml  it's in an xml.  But thank you so much for answering! I do have images, I really appreciate it